# add event once in jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I have something like this :

```
<input class="myClass" id="a" type="checkbox" other="x"/>
<input class="myClass" id="b" type="checkbox" other="x"/>
<input class="myClass" id="c" type="checkbox" other="x"/>
<input class="myClass" id="d" type="checkbox" other="y"/>
<input class="myClass" id="e" type="checkbox" other="z"/>
```

I can retrieve the element a to e, add a click event and I want to add an event on the element define in the attribut `other` (x, y and z).
How can I do it?
I try :

```
$(".myClass").each( function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("other")).click( function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

But three elements have `other="x"` so the event is add three time on x and I want just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better ways, but you could unbind any previous event handlers of this type, using [namespaces *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events):

```
$(".myClass").each( function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("other")).off('click.someNS').on('click.someNS', function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

Another way would be to filter the elements so that you only have one of each with a certain `other` attribute:

```
var seen = {};

$(".myClass").filter(function() {
    var other = $(this).attr('other');
    return !seen[other] && (seen[other] = true);
}).each(...);
```

Comment: I went with the "off-on" solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I unbind the events before binding new one. [Demo on JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6ccN/3/)

```
$(".myClass").each( function() {
    $("#" + $(this).attr("other")).unbind('click').click(    function() {
       alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: That would still add the event handler three times to `x`.

Comment: Infact each iterates all elements with other=x for and you are rightly pointing. Now I changed my answer I hope it is fine now.

Comment: This binds the event handler to the input elements and not to the elements referred to in the `other` attribute.